# BOOL to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, boolean

If I have a method that returns a `BOOL`, how do I cast that to an `NSString` so I can print it out in console?

For example, I tried doing this, which isn't working:

```
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString:", ([thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

But I really want to actually turn the return value into an NSString. I know it's a primitive data type, so I can't call methods on it.  Do I have to create a string separately and then use the Bool as a parameter in a method on NSString?

Comment: The problem with your statement is simply that you didn't include any format specifiers in the first argument to NSLog.  Has nothing to do with BOOL or not.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need a formatting specifier in your format string:

```
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", ([thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Answer (score 65):

Use a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:#C):

```
BOOl isKind= [thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];

NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %d", isKind);
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", isKind ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: You are missing '@' in front of those strings.

Answer (score 33):

In the background BOOL acts like an int type so you can use %i to test for a BOOL type’s value in NSLog:

```
BOOL a = YES;
BOOL b = NO;
NSLog(@"a is %i and b is %i", a, b);

// Output: a is 1 and b is 0
```

Answer (score 23):

So, I know that this is really old, but I thought I might as well toss my solution into the ring. I do:

```
#define NSStringFromBOOL(aBOOL)    ((aBOOL) ? @"YES" : @"NO")
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", NSStringFromBOOL([thing isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
```

I feel that this is more in line with some of Apple's to-string macros (`NSStringFromClass`, `NSStringFromRect`, `NSStringFromSelector`, and so on), and generally pretty simple to use on-the-fly. Just be sure to put that macro somewhere globally accessible, or frequently imported!

Comment: It's not a good idea to prefix things with NS-. That's Apple's prefix. It leads to quite a bit of frustration when they add it later and your definitions start subtly conflicting.

Comment: But what do you do when the object you're checking is *actually named* NSString?  Calling it anything else wouldn't be representative of what it's checking.

Comment: Agreed with Chuck; the macro would be better named `BOOLToNSString()`. @chroipahtz

Comment: It's not prefixing with NS, it's saying it returns an `NSString`. Yes, it may lead to conflict, but that's because the name uses two Apple types only, not because it has a prefix (which means that removing the NS doesn't solve the problem). If one doesn't want conflicts, one will have to put one's own prefix into any global symbols, in this case `PCPNSStringFromBOOL`.

Comment: Extra parentheses for good measures: `#define NSStringFromBOOL(b) ((b) ? @"YES" : @"NO")`

Answer (score 13):

You print a BOOL like this:

```
NSLog(@"The BOOL value is %s", theBoolValue ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Or, with the new `@` notation, one could do:

```
NSLog(@"The BOOL value is %@", @(theBoolValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

NSLog uses a simple printf-style invocation format its text, and your code example is missing the character sequence needed to embed an object.

This should work:

```
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", ([thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add a formatting specifier `%@`.
It should look like this:

```
NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", ([thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Also you can extract a conversion from `BOOL` to `NSString` with extern function as Apple did with `NSStringFromCGRect`, `NSStringFromClass` etc.

Create utils file or add to existing ones header the following code:

```
//NSString+TypeConversion.h

extern NSString *NSStringFromBOOL(BOOL aBool);
```

And also add the following code into implementation:

```
//NSString+TypeConversion.m

NSString *NSStringFromBOOL(BOOL aBool)
{
    return aBool ? @"YES" : @"NO";
}
```

So now you can use this function in other places and your code become more clear and reusable:

```
#import "NSString+TypesConversion.h"

NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", NSStringFromBOOL([thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is work for me:

```
NSLog(@"The BOOL value is %@", theBoolValue ? "YES" : "NO");
```