# What format specifier should be used for BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string-formatting, nslog, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective c formatting string for boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603802/objective-c-formatting-string-for-boolean)

What `NSLog` `%`-specifier should be used to literally see `YES` or `NO` when printing a `BOOL`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective c formatting string for boolean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603802/objective-c-formatting-string-for-boolean) and [BOOL to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738524/bool-to-nsstring)

Comment: has anybody tried %hhd format specifier for BOOL its working fine for me, it prints 1 for YES and 0 for NO

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
BOOL var = YES;
NSLog(@"var = %@", (var ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

`BOOL` is merely an alias (typedef) for `signed char`.

The specifiers supported by NSLog are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

Comment: Right. No direct way to handle it then? :)

Comment: This is the right way to do it.

Comment: @JAM: The `YES` and `NO` that you put in your code are just `#define YES (BOOL)1` and `#define NO (BOOL)0` -- there's nothing but `signed char`s to be handled as soon as the preprocessor is done.

Comment: @sosborn : I suppose that you *could* define a wrapper class around BOOL that knows to output itself properly when the `%@` format specifier is used, but that would just be silly. :-)

Comment: @JoshCaswell : I actually did take the time to look it up in that header file, but mistyped it here. :P

Comment: Not that I'm complaining, but why do I get so many upvotes for trivial answers like this one, yet so few when it takes me an hour to compose a detailed answer with a full working example program for a complex problem?

Comment: A classic problem, @Emile. Drives me crazy, too. You might like to read about it over on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so

Comment: @JoshCaswell : Hahaha, I love that Bike Shed analogy. Experienced it many times at work.

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C booleans (`BOOL`) are simply `typedef`s to `signed char`. Therefore, they are not objects, and aren't handled any differently from other primitive numbers. If you don't care about seeing `YES` and `NO`, you can simply print them out as you would any other number (with `%d`, for instance). If you *would* like to see `YES` and `NO`, you can follow Emile's suggestion.