# Category for simplified NSLogging of BOOLs

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create code, that would do something like this.

```
NSLogBool(self.propertyName)
```

and the output in the debugger console would be

```
"PropertyName is set to YES."
```

Any hints at how could could I achieve that, and this code would not depend on a particular class, i.e. i would have this as a function usable by any class?

Comment: It's impossible with the specified prototype. self.propertyName refers to the value of the property - there's no way to extract the design-time name of the property from that. The best you can do is `NSLogBool(self, @selector(propertyName))` - this way you can resolve the selector back to a name.

Comment: Great question. Interesting simple solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495980/341994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need it decoupled from any particular class, using the preprocessor and C is your best bet.  Something like this should work just fine.

```
#define NSBOOLLog(x) CFILogBoolean(#x, x)

extern void CFILogBoolean(char *propertyName, BOOL val);

void CFILogBoolean(char *propName, BOOL val) {
    printf("%s is set to %s", propName, (val ? "YES" : "NO"));
}
```

As long as that extern declaration is put into a header (possibly a utility header, or even a common set of typedefs, etc.) that's visible to your compilation units, it can be used freely without having to rely on a class.

Comment: Upvote for using `#x` to get the name of the passed variable.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend digging into the NS-Namespace like this.  Try to re-name the functions with prefixes that go along with your name or the project you're using this with.

Comment: if you'd like to write a solution that's less c-based and more obj-c based you might want to use `SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"propertyName");` as part of your macro

Comment: @bazik that's a macro for a runtime call.  That's not less C, that's more C!

Comment: I ma not sure if posters here understand the requirement. The fundamental goal I want to achieve is to get rid of need to type the property name as NSString into the normal NSLog. Instead I want to create a function that does this for me..so I simply pass a properly "codesensed" property instead.

Comment: @EarlGrey That's what that there function does.  Nowhere do you need to stringify anything to get it work, as the `#` preprocessor token does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Define this `MACRO` in your general constant file or `.pch` file in your project.

```
#define NSLogBool(status)   NSLog(@"%@",(status)?@"YES":@"NO")
```

then simply check the status log using following

```
BOOL status = NO;
NSLog(@"%@",(status)?@"YES":@"NO");
NSLogBool(status);
status = YES;
NSLogBool(status);
```

Comment: Don't prefix it with `NS`, though.  i'd also suggest just having a macro that converts a BOOL to an NSString;  `#define MyNSStringFromBOOL(flag) ((flag)?@"YES":@"NO")`.   Then it can be used in any log statements or `description` implementations.